# How do I replace every nth instance in an ndarray?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, instance, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a numpy array `atoms.numbers` which looks like:

```
array([27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 27, 27,  8,
        8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,
        8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57,
       57, 57, 57, 27, 27,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8])
```

I can replace all of the same instance such as every '57' in the array using:

```
atoms.numbers[atoms.numbers==57]=38
```

which gives:

```
array([27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 27, 27,  8,
        8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,
        8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38,
       38, 38, 38, 27, 27,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8])
```

I would like to be able to replace every nth instance in the array. I have tried:

```
n=5
atoms.numbers[atoms.numbers==57][::n]=38
```

Which does not work.

Comment: What is the purpose of `[atoms.numbers==57]` in the second example? Do you want to replace every 5th number that is equal 57?

Comment: Yes the example was to show that I can replace every instance of '57' in the array. I want to be able to replace every 5th instance of '57' in the array with '38'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where` to find the indexes of the items of interest. Find every n'th index. Update the items:

```
locations = np.where(numbers == 57)[0]
numbers[locations[::n]] = 38
```